# How to make a queuing system?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Bellow I have some code which downloads videos. The code downloads videos form a string i provide it with and can only download one video per call. My question is can i make a queuing systems that can start the next provided string straight after simutanuously.
Thanks In advance

```
 -(IBAction)download{



    LBYouTubeExtractor *extractor = [[LBYouTubeExtractor alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL.text] quality:LBYouTubeVideoQualityLarge];

    [extractor extractVideoURLWithCompletionBlock:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {

            NSLog(@"Did extract video URL using completion block: %@", videoURL);
            NSURL *url = videoURL;


            [extractor extractVideoURLWithCompletionBlock:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error) {


                if(!error) {




                    NSLog(@"Did extract video URL using completion block: %@", videoURL);


                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                                            filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@.mp4", NSHomeDirectory(),title.text];
                        filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"video_%@.mp4"), videoURL];
                        data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: videoURL];
                        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                        NSLog(@"File %@ successfully saved", filePath);


                    }

                                   );


                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Failed extracting video URL using block due to error:%@", error);
                }
            }];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed extracting video URL using block due to error:%@", error);
        }

    }];

}
```

Comment: This is a very common pattern and so you probably don't want to reinvent the wheel, if you can avoid it. I would recommend looking at `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation`s to do this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html).

It's fairly trivial to create an NSOperationQueue with a [maxConcurrentOperationCount](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/maxConcurrentOperationCount) of 1, and pass your queue blocks of code to perform using [addOperationWithBlock](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperationQueue/addOperationWithBlock%3a). In your case, you could loop through the list of videos and enqueue each download to your NSOperationQueue.